# How to mock a axios post with Vue + Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, axios

I'm trying to test a method in Vue through Jest, and I have to test an Axios request within this method.

I have already searched for several solutions, but I have not found one that matches my scenario, I am not able to test this request, even though I have used moxios, and other npm packages

````js
// config.vue
methods: {
    async config () {
      await axios.post('/users/config')
        .then(res => {
          if (res.data.success) {
            M.toast({html: res.data.message, classes: 'green'})
            this.$router.push('/tour')
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          M.toast({html: 'Não foi possível contactar, ou você não possui permissão!', classes: 'red'})
        })
    }
  }
```js
// config.spec.js

import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import config from '@/components/config'
import axios from '@/axios-auth'
jest.mock('axios')

const localVue = createLocalVue()


describe('config', () => {
  const spy = jest.fn()

  it('mocking axios request', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(config, {
      localVue
    })
    wrapper.vm.config()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/users/config', 'post', {success: true, message: 'Configuração realizada!'})
  })
})
````

Comment: You may try two ways to test your code: a mock creation or extract the axios call to an external method / function to test the vue component and this call separately. What do you think is more suitable to you?